# vis.js - how to run the getSeed() method

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I'm using vis.js to create some maps of data. In the documentation it says

> "Ideally you try with an undefined seed, reload until you are happy
>   with the layout and use the `getSeed()` method to ascertain the seed."
>
> However, for the life of me I can't figure out how to "use the
>   `getSeed()` method".

I assume it is a function but everytime I try it I get told

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: getSeed is not defined"

Can someone let me know how to run this. I am sure it is really obvious, but after a day of searching I am none the wiser.

I tried:

```
getSeed();
vis.getSeed();
var seed = getSeed();
```

I also placed this into various places in my script, but to no avail.

Comment: For those who comes here when using Neovis, see [When using Neovis library, how to pass Vis.js' methods to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69665265/3416774)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those docs you reference are related to the `Network` type. So if you create a Network with something like the following:

```
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options)
```

Then you should be able to call `network.getSeed()`.

You can see the definition at line 477 [here](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/5563fc616885578ad51b2dfa6ccf70ccebf06126/lib/network/Network.js).

Comment: OK cheers. I knew it would be something obvious. That was probably one of the few variations I didn't try.

Comment: line 477 is `Network.prototype.getSeed = function() {return this.layoutEngine.getSeed.apply(this.layoutEngine,arguments);};`. If possible, can you explain what it does?

Comment: If you follow the source code, you will see it goes to a function that returns `Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000);`