# When using Neovis library, how to pass Vis.js' methods to the console?

Tags: javascript, methods, console.log, vis.js-network, neovis

I use [neovis.js](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js) to build a graph, which imports [vis.js](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/layout.html). Vis.js's documentation guides me to pass `getSeed()` method to the console. How should I do this?

I've tried these to no avail:

- `getSeed();`
- `NeoVis.getSeed();`
- `viz._config.visConfig.getSeed();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source at `neovis.d.ts`, you will see this line:

```
/**
 * The vis network object
 * @link https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#methods
 */
get network(): VisNetwork.Network | undefined;
```

And in your Neovis script you should have this:

```js
viz = new NeoVis.default(config)
```

This is equivalent with `var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options)` in Vis.js' tutorial. So all you need is to use `viz.network.getSeed()` in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used either of the packages that you've mentioned, but I did some digging and was able to find another user who was struggling with the same issue. Apparently the documentation you're looking at is referencing the *Network* type, so you'll need to instantiate a *Network* in order to use the `getSeed()` method

The answerer on the actual question page explained it more clearly, check it out:
[vis.js - how to run the getSeed() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306769/vis-js-how-to-run-the-getseed-method)

Hopefully this helps a bit!